# How to implement an 'immediate search' TextBox in C# with auto-complete.

Tags: c#

I want to implement automatic data sorting in a `TextBox` that begins as soon as a user types something into it, without moving the cursor. For example: As the user types 'c', the mechanism will start sorting with words starting with the letter 'c' and automatically complete the input with the results. I need this project in C#.

Comment: do you want this in web form or windows from?

Comment: i need its coding in web form

Comment: i need to bind gridview as text typed in textboxed immediately

Comment: then you should `Immediately` do a google search

Comment: not getting the answers

Comment: We are not here to do your work you will definitely get `HELP` once you show some `EFFORT` on your end first

Answer (score 2):

Just try to implement the event of TextBox [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then write your logic into it

```
    private void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    { ResultBox.Text= FilterData(SearchBox.Text); }
```

And I suggest you to filter your data with LINQ.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this link might help you [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb397940.aspx). Put this stuff inside the method "FilterData" that @Lelezeus wrote before

Answer (score 0):

i guess what you are searching for is `auto-complete` you can start with [jquery-ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)